# How to retrieve all values from Unique Key Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I want to retrieve the value from Firebase unique key in flutter, the Firebase structure is like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZHve.jpg

here my code

```dart
void showTemperature(){
 final databaseRefences = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Monitoring").child("s
Suhu");
 databaseReferences.once().then((Datasnapshot snapshot){
  Map <dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
  values.forEach((key, values){
    print(value[key]);
   });
 });
}
```

the output of retrieve data I want is like this

> 43.70 *c
>   48.20 *c
>   33.90 *c
>   26.10 *c
>   38.10 *c

anyone can help me to retrieve data like this in flutter?

Comment: Are you getting anything right now?

Comment: nope, it has no ouput

Comment: You have an additional 's' in your "child" and you should add an `await` before `Firebase.instance....` I believe.

Comment: it's a typo. and still not print anything when i remove it

Comment: Have you included `await` and made your method `async`?

Comment: yes i do. still has same problem

Comment: What happens if you include `print("snapshot: ${snapshot.value}");` before creating a map?

Comment: it has the following output.

snapshot : {-Linph-uVFNQFgXZK_WB: 43.70 *C, -LinpoQTrLGLZTyMFztg: 48.20 *C, -Linq9cD4ZDXXcpZiBeU: 38.10 *C, -LinpvotYQ20KzPpfOVm: 33.90 *C, -Linq2DbG4Yy9zMDVDOi: 26.10 *C}

Comment: Can it be a typo in your `forEach()` - you print value[key] without **s**? If that's not the case then simply print `values` in the for loop and see what the outcome will be.

Comment: it has the following output even when i add s  like this values[key], the output is
E/flutter ( 4232): #0      tampilSuhu.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:syspln/main.dart:184:19)
E/flutter ( 4232): #1      __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:367:8)

Comment: Okay, then that is not the solution. If you only print value (omitting [keys]) inside forEach() what is the outcome?

Comment: it's work. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be caused by minor errors. To conclude, the solution to the problem is the following:

```dart
Future<void> showTemperature() async { // making this both a Future and async method
 final databaseRefences = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Monitoring").child("Suhu");
 databaseReferences.once().then((Datasnapshot snapshot){
  Map <dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
  values.forEach((key, values){
    print(value); // omitting "[keys]" from the OPs approach
   });
 });
}
```

Please mark this as the correct solution to your problem and let me know if I this differ from your implemented solution.